# How do I find and kill an application which keeps restarting?

Tags: macos, xcode, launchd, login-items

I am writing an application in Swift and I have attempted to allow it to launch at login by following a number of tutorials. This involves creating a launcher application and enabling it using `SMLoginItemSetEnabled`.

Things have gone horribly wrong. I followed the instructions to remove the main storyboard, but neglected to remove its reference in `Info.plist`. I think that as a result the launcher application crashes.

However the real problem is that I am now in an an endless loop. I get an alert that the launcher quit unexpectedly. Ignore simply restarts it, and Report… does the same. I cannot get it to stop restarting.

I have logged out, restarted, and also done so without reopening windows. I cannot find anything in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/`, and, indeed, I can’t find the application anywhere.

In my `/var/log/system.log` I get:

> Service exited due to SIGABRT
> Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.

How do I go about finding this process and killing it once and for all?

Comment: Only you know how you enabled allowing an _application_ to load when you _log in_. Look at the directions you followed to enable it.  That said, if you reboot to safe mode, it should stop it from being in an endless loop so you can remove whatever from wherever you enable it. Have a look at: [Start up your Mac in safe mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/start-up-your-mac-in-safe-mode-mh21245/mac). That said, I learned a long time ago never test software I'm writing on the physical machine until it's been throughly tested in a virtual machine. It saves a lot of headaches!

Answer (score 2):

You fix this simply by deleting the .application bundle. Then fix the problem with `Info.plist` in Xcode and rebuild.